# The theory of two finite linear orders

Tags: lo.logic, decidability, linear-orders

My colleague Matthias Baaz is looking for a reference for the following question (or possibly theorem):

Let T be the "theory of pairs of finite linear orders".  That is, consider all finite structures $(X, R, S)$ where $R$ and $S$ are linear orders on $X$. Let T be the set of all first order formulas (in the language $=, R, S$) which are valid in all those (finite) models.

Clearly T is $\Pi^0_1$.  Is T undecidable (or even $\Pi^0_1$-complete, as in Trakhtenbrot's theorem)? This should be well known.

Comment: Interesting tangent: this theory does not have a 01-law. P. Winkler, [A counterexample in the theory of random orders](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF00353655), Order 5 (1989), 363-368.

Comment: The undecidability of $T$, with a reference, is mentioned in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/52626/undecidability-degree-of-some-elementary-theories-two-equivalence-relations .

Comment: Thank you! That was really an answer, not a comment.